# how to get rendering variant using c#

Tags: sitecore-mvc, c#

I have a list of renderings used in an item. I used below code

```
Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] renderings = null;
renderings = Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
foreach (var rendering in renderings){

}
```

Is it possible to get which rendering variant is being used for all renderings? These all are SXA renderings.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the rendering variant through rendering parameters. As it's a drop-down, it provides you with the GUID i.e the Sitecore ID of the rendering variant. Subsequently, you can retrieve its details through the GetItem method. Please refer the below code,

```
Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] renderings = null;
renderings = Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
foreach (var rendering in renderings){
 var parms = rendering.Parameters;
 renderingVariantItemID= parms["Variant"]; 
 Item renderingVariantItem = rSitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(renderingVariantItemID));
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add any reference it's showing an error that renderingReferance does not contain a definition of the parameter?
i am currently using 
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

Comment: .Parameters are available inside "Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation", so you need to add this reference. @Vinesh

Answer (score 0):

```
Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] renderings = Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
```

foreach (var rendering in renderings)
{
// Check if the rendering is an SXA rendering
if (rendering.RenderingItem != null && rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem.TemplateName.Equals("Rendering Variant"))
{
// Get the rendering variant ID from the rendering settings
var variantId = rendering.Settings["Variation ID"];

```
    // Get the rendering variant item based on the ID
    var variantItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(variantId);

    // You can now access properties of the rendering variant item, such as its name
    if (variantItem != null)
    {
        var variantName = variantItem["Name"];
        // Do something with the rendering variant information
    }
}
```

}